# mainwindow.ui and dialog.ui to set/read communication date

Tags: c++, qt, c++11

I have two windows: **mainwindow.ui** and **dialog.ui**. In the **mainwindow.cpp** I initialise some objects on the heap of another class for Ethernet-communication and use functions of these objects to read date from the bus and show the values in the **mainwindow.ui**. In **dialog.ui** I would like to set the values on the bus, but the problem is to access the communication-functions and objects in **mainwindow.cpp**.
I wanted to define dialog.cpp as friend class, but I make something wrong. Here is some code:

**mainwindow.h**

```
class MainWindow : public QMainWindow 
{protected: DateReg *myPosReg;...}
```

**mainwindow.cpp**

```
...   
myPosReg = new DateReg(DateValue->AddReg());
...
myPosReg->GetValue(a,b,c);
myPosReg->setValue(a,b,c);
    ...
```

Can I somehow access *setValue()* function in **dialog.cpp**?  Should I allways use **dialog.cpp** for the **dialog.ui** or there is some possibility work with **dialog.ui**-date in **mainwindow.cpp**? To set the values in **dialog.ui** I use QDoubleSpinBox. 
In the **mainwindow.ui** I call **dialog.ui**.
Excuse me for my English.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I understand, you have two classes: `MainWindow` and `Dialog`. As `MainWindow::myPosReg` is protected, you can only access it in `Dialog`, if `Dialog` derives from `MainWindow` or if it is a friend.

The following design should work:

```
class MainWindow : public QMainWindow 
{
    [...]
  protected: 
    DateReg *myPosReg; 
    friend class Dialog; 
};

class Dialog
{
    [...]
    MainWindow* myMainWindow;

    void someFunction()
    {
        myMainWindow->myPosReg->setValue([...]);
    }
};
```

As an alternative, I would suggest a more Qt-ish way by using signals and slots. When the spin-boxes in `Dialog` change, emit a signal to which `MainWindow` listens.

We start with the dialog:

```
class Dialog : public QDialog
{
    [...]
    Dialog()
    {
        [...init ui...]
        connect(ui->spinBoxA, SIGNAL(valueChanged(int)),
                this, SLOT(onSpinBoxValueChanged()));
        connect(ui->spinBoxB, SIGNAL(valueChanged(int)),
                this, SLOT(onSpinBoxValueChanged()));
        connect(ui->spinBoxC, SIGNAL(valueChanged(int)),
                this, SLOT(onSpinBoxValueChanged()));
    }

  signals:
    void valuesChanged(int a, int b, int c);

  private slots:
    void onSpinBoxValueChanged()
    {
        emit valuesChanged(ui->spinBoxA->value(), ui->spinBoxB->value(),
                           ui->spinBoxC->value());
    }
};
```

So the dialog has an internal slot `onSpinBoxValueChanged()`, which is called when
one of the spinboxes changes its value. The sole purpose of this slot is to emit
another signal `valuesChanged` to which we'll connect the main window (i.e. the
dialog's internal slot combines three values into one signal).

The main window could be the following:

```
class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    [...]
    DateReg *myPosReg;
  public slots:
    void setValues(int a, int b, int c)
    {
        myPosReg->setValues(a, b, c);
    }
};
```

And the code, which connects both

```
int main()
{
    [...]
    MainWindow* mainWindow = new MainWindow;
    Dialog* dialog = new Dialog;
    connect(dialog, SIGNAL(valuesChanged(int,int,int)),
            mainWindow, SLOT(setValues(int,int,int)));
}
```

When the user changes the value in a spinbox, the following chain-reaction happens:

```
QSpinBox::valueChanged(int) -> Dialog::onSpinBoxValueChanged() 
  -> Dialog::valuesChanged() -> MainWindow::setValues() -> DateReg::setValues()
```

The advantage is that you decouple `MainWindow` and `Dialog`: `Dialog` just signals that the values have changed but does not care what happens with them and `MainWindow` changes its `myPosReg` but does not care, where the values are coming from.

Comment: Mehrwolf, thank you very much. It`s great! The second solution is what I need.

Comment: But I would like to resume the all values simultaneously with a "Resume"/"Übernehmen" button so that the Dialog-window not close. But if I realise it with accept() signal then Dialog-window is closing :((

Comment: Then instead of `connect(ui->spinBoxA..) connect(ui->spinBoxB..) connect(ui->spinBoxC..)` I need only one   `connect(ui->pushButton, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(onSpinBoxValueChanged()));` Is right?

Comment: **@Mehrwolf**, I would like to give you a reputation point, but I have not enough reputation. Thank you very much

Comment: @ViktorTarasov: The dialog closes, if `QDialog::accept()` is called. I think, if you create your own QPushButton and do not connect `QPushButton::clicked()` to `QDialog::accept()`, the dialog should stay open.

Comment: @ViktorTarasov: If this answer is suitable for your question, just accept it by clicking on the checkmark ([see here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235)). This is the way, how you give reputation to another person (don't worry, you will not lose reputation).